# Possibly Malicious code execution on startup

Tags: windows, boot, powershell, malware, rootkit

Checked my event viewer to see if my system was starting any funny commands. This is due to the fact i noticed a sudden slowdown on my pc after startup.

Im wondering if an event like this is normal; Particularly im worried why it is an event executing powershell with 'ExecutionPolicy - Unrestricted'. This is the event viewer log:

```
Engine state is changed from Available to Stopped. 

Details:    NewEngineState=Stopped  PreviousEngineState=Available

    SequenceNumber=15

    HostName=ConsoleHost    HostVersion=5.1.22621.963   HostId=0164a692-3bb4-4c12-a309-a980519310f6     HostApplication=**powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -InputFormat Text
-NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command -**  EngineVersion=5.1.22621.963     RunspaceId=703eb2af-1dc0-4686-97a5-15feaf371af3     PipelineId=     CommandName=    CommandType=    ScriptName=     CommandPath=    CommandLine=
```

Comment: "Does windows have any business executing a command like this on startup?" - Yes; There is nothing specifically malicious about launching PowerShell without a profile. Unless you analyze the script that is ran itself.  Your event log isn't conclusive one way or another.

Comment: If you post this type of text, please format it as `code` not as a > quote.

Comment: Hi RamHound, i was worried about the 'ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted' section. I am not well versed with powershell. Does this cmdlet apply allow unsigned scripts across the board or specific to script/application it is running for

Comment: @NS Please [edit] your question and add requested information or clarification to the question.

Comment: @Ramhound Im unsure how to find out the script this event viewer is referring to. Would you know how?

Comment: @Bodo ive changed the formatting of my event viewer log from a quote to a code. Additionally ive clarified that I am unable to provide additional information as I am unsure how to do so (Regarding another user's question)

Comment: @NS - If you suspect an script is automatically ran at start-up then running [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) can help find it.  However, if you can't determine what script is being ran, there might not be a script actually being ran.

Comment: You wrote in a comment that you were worried about `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`. If you have a question about this, add it to the question.

Comment: @Bodo Okay will edit following

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for insight and tip. I will try determine with Autoruns

Comment: All clarification what you want to know or what you are having problems with should be in the question, so a new reader would find everything in one place, not scattered in comments.

Comment: If autoruns is a bust, windows has what is called "powershell script block logging" with various levels of detail.

Comment: @Yorik. This, thanks i ran into it yesterday, alongside learning some stuff about script execution. Thing is im not sure where the script logging happens, is it just in event viewer or is there a custom log file